# Get column value to another column in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7, react-table-v6

What I am trying to do is to show the toggle value in another column.

[image]

I have this column value and data.

[image]

Since, accessor cant be duplicate. Is there another way to show the Toggle value in the Status column?

The Toggle data is updated when toggled, so I just need a way to show it.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a code sandbox with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769692/how-to-pass-the-toggle-value-in-another-column-in-react-table I did, but no one answered. So I provide an image instead

Comment: does the sandbox have your current code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell: (row) => row.row.original.toggle.toString()
```

I only this.